# I am receiving \\r\\n on carriage return instead of \r\n

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, carriage-return

The project uses sockets to read from a connecting client until either there is no more characters to be read or it receives a \r\n. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
while True:
    ch = connection.recv(1)
    data += ch.decode('UTF-8')
    if data.endswith('\r\n') or not ch:
        data = data.replace('\r\n','')
        break
```

The code works as intended when windows is used to run the server that reads from clients. However when I try to run it on a raspberry pi running rasbian, it always reads a carriage return as '\\r\\n'. For example when a client sends:

```
-list_networks wlan0 5180<return>
```

yields a string looking like:

```
-list_networks wlan0 5180\\r\\n
```

Why is this? Because of this it does not get read as a carriage return and is missed. I know different OS return different of strings for carriage return but I didn't find anything about this string when I researched a bit. Am I missing something? Suggestions and explanations are appreciated.

### edit:

Forgot to add the command is sent through a telnet connection. I want to be able to connect to the socket via telnet. Type a command and when the enter key is pressed the command the loop will recognize and end the loop.

Comment: What's the result of `print repr(data)`?

Comment: We have no clue how you're sending it.

Comment: The command is being sent through telnet

Comment: Every time I've seen this previously, it was a result of a [potentially implicit] `repr()` call where someone wanted `str()` instead. If you provided enough code to reproduce, we could see where that was.

Comment: ...which is to say: How do you know that that's what's happening? What handling you do with the string *after* the point where it's received (which you show us), up to and including the point where it's printed?

Comment: (on a different point -- the telnet protocol is *not* a raw socket connection; I'd suggest using `nc`, `netcat` or `socat` rather than `telnet` unless you know what you're doing and why; see an overview of the use of an in-band control channel in the wikipedia article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet).